# Import resources and create VM from image using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

Im trying to import the resources and and create VM from the existing image on Azure. All the imports are successful but when I run terraform apply, I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf0qd.png)

here is the code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "2.0.0"
    subscription_id = var.subscriptionID

    features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "TerraformResourceGroup" {

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "TerraformSecurityGroup" {

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "TerraformVirtualNetwork" {

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "TerraformNetworkInterface" {

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "TerraformVM" {
  name                  = var.VM
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.TerraformNetworkInterface.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

 storage_image_reference {
    id  = "/subscriptions/--/resourceGroups/TerraformResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/TerraformVM-image-20210201164126"
}

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "disk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = var.name
    admin_username = var.username
    admin_password = var.password
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
     provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Please help

Ok, Let me explain a bit clear. I created a rg and deployed a vm using terraform, then captured the VM. now I need to deploy a vm using that image in same rg. Do I need to use import or data sources? if I use data source I'm getting the following:Error deleting Virtual Network "xx" (Resource Group "yy"): network.VirtualNetworksClient#Delete: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted" Message="Subnet xx is in use by /subscriptions/--/resourceGroups/yy/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/xx/ipConfigurations/internal and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet.
Code using data sources

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "2.0.0"
    subscription_id = var.subscriptionID

    features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "TerraformResourceGroup" {
  name     = var.resourceGroupName
}

data "azurerm_network_security_group" "TerraformSecurityGroup" {
  name                = var.securityGroup
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "TerraformVirtualNetwork" {
  name                = var.virtualNetwork
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "TerraformSubNet" {
  name                 = var.subnet
  virtual_network_name = var.virtualNetwork
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
    name                         = var.publicIP
    location                     = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.location}"
    resource_group_name          = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name}"
    allocation_method            = "Static"

}

# create a network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "TerraformNetworkInterface" {
  name                = var.networkInterface
  location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.TerraformSubNet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
   // public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "TerraformVM" {
  name                  = var.VM
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.TerraformResourceGroup.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.TerraformNetworkInterface.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

 storage_image_reference {
    id  = "/subscriptions/----/resourceGroups/TerraformResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/TerraformVM-image-20210202111108"
    }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "Imagedisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = var.name
    admin_username = var.username
    admin_password = var.password
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
     provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, you are missing parameters in **azurerm_network_interface**.

You need to add **location** and **resource_group_name** in **resource "azurerm_network_interface"**:

Here is an example:

```
    provider "azurerm" {
        version = "2.0.0"
        subscription_id = var.subscriptionID
    
        features {}
    }

    variable "prefix" {
         default = "tfvmex"
     }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "TerraformResourceGroup" {
      name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
      location = "West US 2"
    }
   resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "TerraformSecurityGroup" {

   }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "TerraformVirtualNetwork" {
      name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "TerraformNetworkInterface" {
      name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    

    }
    
    ......
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc about [Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine).

Answer (score 0):

The [Terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html) command does not generate a Terraform resource configuration. Instead, it imports your existing resources into **Terraform’s state**.

After importing your existing resources into the state file. You need to manually create a corresponding resource configuration file referring to the information provided by the state and manage your existing infrastructure with Terraform.

For example, you can run [terraform show](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/show.html), which provides human-readable output from a state or plan file.
[image]

Then you can copy the attributes of `name` and `location` and contents to fill the block of

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "TerraformResourceGroup" {
    location = "westeurope"
    name     = "nancyexample-resources"
}
```

You can fill the remaining blocks in the same way. After that, you can check for errors in your configuration by running the `terraform plan` command. Terraform plan shows you the changes that would take place if you were to apply the configurations with the `terraform apply` command. If there are any arguments missing or not set, you can modify your configuration file to meet the requirements.

Once you have verified the configurations, you can run `terraform apply` to create the new resources. For more information, see [Import Terraform configuration](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/state-import).

Comment: In this case, you could use the data source to query the existing resource when you deploy a new resource. If you want to keep the original resources, you should rename or remove the original file `terraform.tfstate` and run `terrafrom init`, plan, apply after that.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the old terraform.tfstate then run terraform commands again?

Comment: Could you show more steps to reproduce this issue?